# Width of div with margin different in IE than firefox

Tags: html, css, layout, quirks-mode

I'm working on a user control that does an asynchronous post to the server. I want the user control to fade and display a "Sending..." message and gif while it's working. To do so I'm trying to absolutely position a semi-transparent div overtop of the control's main div. It's turning out to be a lot harder than it should be. I finally got it looking ok in firefox but go into IE and find that the control's main div is not even the correct width.

I want the total width to be 275px. So in firefox I styled it to have

```
width: 245px; margin 36px 15px 46px 15px;
```

So the width + the margin = 275 and that's how it renders. In IE, the browser is subtracting the margin from the width so the total width is 245 with the 15px margins inside that. Well I found out both browsers are running in quirks mode despite ... I think ... the doc type being:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN>
```

My understanding is this is what quirks mode is supposed to do, but when IE and Firefox render it differently even though both are in quirks mode, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Your doctype is incorrect. It should be: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` However, I would just use the simpler HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Hopefully, if you have no other errors that will mean that both browsers operate in standards allowing you to alignin the div easily.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've been reading mixed things on the effects of doctype declarations. The only problem is, that doctype is on the master page of our main, public facing website, so at this point I don't think I can change it.

Comment: Well there is no point in having a doctype that is incorrect. The browsers will just end up in quirks mode. So you might as well change it. Can you provide a link to the site? You can test how the site will look with the correct doctype i.e. standards mode. Just open up the IE developer tools (Press F12) and change the browser + document mode to IE9 standards.

Comment: Thanks, I updated to the full transitional mode to get it running in standards mode. Quirks sucks. Nothing I'm trying to do works right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to respond if you posted a link, but if my assumptions are correct, you can force IE modes by using meta tags that look like this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Obviously it would be different depending on what version you want to use. Similarly you are able to force out of compatible mode, into quirks mode, etc. I've never had this issue in Firefox so can't speak to that, but I would imagine Mozilla has something similar.

I think your problem would be better solved by setting the box model, though. Use this CSS class on the block elements in question

```
#yourdiv { box-sizing: border-box }
```

This will help alleviate the pains of different browsers' rendering of the box model. More info on box-sizing [here](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Also, don't forget about `display: block` as sometimes this will fix oddities.